# Console Interface With Boxes

Tags: c#, user-interface, console

Suppose i have the following interface on a C# Console Application:

[image]

And i would like to write something the user tells me to write (his name for example), and it would leave the interface like this:

[image]

Is there a way to write inside of that? maybe thinking about the location of the cursor could work? i've tried to do it but i dont know how to do it fine, so it doesnt work?

To generate thos 3 boxes of  '*'  I would use a "for" from the beginning of the console till the end, and i would place the '*' as i need.

Comment: This is a bit vague. What if the string (e.g. name) doesn't fit in those boxes? And do you actually want the user to be typing directly into the box?

Comment: It is a bad idea to draw GUI in console. Eventually you will run into a wall of "can't do that unless you spend a lot of time figuring a workaround". Console is not meant for GUI, so don't spend your time learning something that is not useful. Go for WPF instead and proper windows.

Comment: Im not doing this because i want to, its for a project that i have to hand in, and it has to be done this way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think moving the cursor each time is not really a good idea. Your program will contain a lot of logic to place the cursor at precise positions, you'll have a lot of magic numbers, and so on.

An alternative would be to simply draw your boxes, and then after each input [`Clear()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.clear%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the console and redraw them. So your main loop would ask for a name, store it and redraw your boxes with the new input. To draw the box, simply loop on all your names (even empty ones) and [`Pad`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36f2hz3a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) them to have exactly the same length on each row.

Here is a complete example so you can see and understand the behavior *(I've also hard-capped the input to 8 characters and 5 names to prevent edge cases, you can edit that quickly with the constants. And sorry for the messy StoreUserAnswer method)*. As you'll see, clearing the console do not flicker the screen.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        private const int MAX_NAME_LENGTH = 8;
        private const int MAX_NAMES = 5;

        private static string[] names = new string[MAX_NAMES];
        private static int currentIndex;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DrawBox();

            while (true)
            {
                AskForAName();
                StoreUserAnswer();
                DrawBox();
            }
        }

        private static void AskForAName()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a name:");
        }

        private static void StoreUserAnswer()
        {
            string name = Console.ReadLine() ?? string.Empty;
            if (name.Length > MAX_NAME_LENGTH)
            {
                name = name.Substring(0, MAX_NAME_LENGTH);
            }

            names[currentIndex] = name;
            currentIndex++;
            if (currentIndex > MAX_NAMES - 1)
            {
                currentIndex = 0;
            }
        }

        private static void DrawBox()
        {
            Console.Clear();
            DrawDelimiter();
            DrawNames();
            DrawDelimiter();
        }

        private static void DrawDelimiter()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("*{0}*", new String('*', MAX_NAME_LENGTH));
        }

        private static void DrawNames()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < MAX_NAMES; i++)
            {
                DrawName(names[i] ?? string.Empty);
            }
        }

        private static void DrawName(string name)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("*{0}*", name.PadRight(MAX_NAME_LENGTH, ' '));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I will work using this things you gave me, ill make good use of it! Cant thank you enough!

Answer (score 1):

you want [Console.SetCursorPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setcursorposition%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

something like:

```
Console.SetCursorPosition(10,0);
Console.Write("Carl");
```

You can do a decent amount with the Console.  Look through the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.console)

Comment: Yeah but my problem was, how would i know which coordinate to use with SetCursorPosition. Thanks for the reply!